# Is there a valid alternative to top for OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, top

I like very much htop, on GNU/Linux is very nice, I would like a similar software for OpenBSD 5.6. Anyone knows something about that?

Comment: Damn, I know perfectly that OpenBSD doesn't have /proc filesystem, my question is on 'similar' software.

Comment: OpenBSD dropping proc was rediculous.   As if the only people in the world accessing proc were kernel developers, and since that code was removed, then proc was obsolete.   Countless (really, you can't count them) scripting, monitoring, etc. tool used /proc, and OpenBSD is just broken for all of that.   htop is just one victim of this decision.

Comment: @ErikAronesty AFAIK procfs was never part of POSIX (it was cloned from Plan 9 in 4.4BSD IIRC) so I'm not sure why it's such a big deal for them to drop it.  FreeBSD has been moving towards dropping it too.

Comment: @ErikAronesty : remember, "broken" is just a point of view, this is not a site promoting opinions, but answers. You see, your comment helped nobody, that is to say it was not only useless also you offered an opinion no one asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From **OpenBSD 5.9** `htop` is available as a package and it works very well.

To install it, use

```
pkg_add htop
```

as root.

Answer (score 7):

Htop 2.0 adds OpenBSD support. I just compiled it on OpenBSD 5.9 and it works very well: http://hisham.hm/htop/

Answer (score 4):

`systat(1)`, `top(1)` and `ps` are your best choices.

At some point you were able to mount `procfs` on OpenBSD - see `mount_procfs(8)` but this was [recently removed](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sys/arch/i386/conf/files.i386.diff?r1=1.217&r2=1.218&f=h) from the standard configuration. You can try to build a custom kernel, but I expect procfs support was removed for a good reason.

For example, see this commented out line in `/usr/src/sys/arch/i386/conf/GENERIC`

```
#option          PROCFS          # /proc, currently broken
```

You can try to build a new kernel with `procfs` support. It's only supported on i386 and is broken in 5.6 (as far as I can tell).

```
cd /tmp; wget http://ftp.spline.de/pub/OpenBSD/5.6/sys.tar.gz
tar xzf /tmp/sys.tar.gz # Unpack sources
cd /usr/src/sys/arch/i386/conf
vi GENERIC # Comment out the procfs line
config GENERIC
cd ../compile/GENERIC
make clean && make
make install
reboot
```

Now you can mount `procfs`:

```
mount_procfs /proc /proc
```

Build htop (it requires procfs and is only supported on Linux. Technically it works on FreeBSD as well, with the procfs mounted, and *may* end up working on OpenBSD... your mileage may vary. I wouldn't trust it though...

```
wget http://hisham.hm/htop/releases/1.0/htop-1.0.tar.gz
tar zxf htop-1.0.tar.gz
cd htop-1.0
./configure
make
make install
```

Or really, just use `top` instead...

Answer (score 1):

htop is Linux only software and apparently works on FreeBSD and NetBSD via Linux compatibility layer (probably only on 32bit). OpenBSD Linux comp (386 only) is on the life support. However check out OpenBSD top, and sysctl. Few people mentioned /proc (procfs). Of course OpenBSD doesn't have it. That is Plan 9 special filesystem which was shamelessly stolen by Linux.

Comment: the /proc filesystem predates plan9 by long. it already existed in svr4

Answer (score 0):

You can install htop using brew. https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

```
$ brew install htop
```

Comment: Isn't `brew` OSX-specific? I remember for most usecases it needs XCode.

Comment: The Homebrew package manager may be used on Linux and Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Homebrew was formerly referred to as Linuxbrew when running on Linux or WSL. https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

Comment: Homebrew does not run on OpenBSD. `htop` is available through OpneBSD's native package system: `pkg_add htop`

Comment: @JonathanWoodward : ok, Linux or WSL, not OpenBSD.